# I can't force this image to 100% in Firefox?

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

The code is here:

```php
    <div class="entry-page-image">
        <div class="featured-image-container">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-page-image -->
```

Effected by this css:

```css
.entry-page-image { position: fixed; display: inline-block; top: 0; margin: 0 0 30px 30px;  margin-left: 260px; float:left; width: 100%; }

.featured-image-container { height: 100%; width: auto;  }

.featured-image-container img { height: 100%; width: auto;  }
```

However in Firefox the browser takes the standard 1024px high image, and wont scale it down to be 100% of the browser window height. I'm aware this is quite a common problem, but I can't seem to rephrase my code to the right effect.

Anyone fancy shifting it about for me?

Comment: The output of <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?> is http://zoesghanakitchen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013-06-11-12.51.43-764x1024.jpg That image.

It's a bit too large for the screen, but on Chrome, IE etc it stretches to fit 100% of the height, and width: auto makes it the right shape.

Firefox, again fairly notoriously, doesn't handle it in that way. I just can't work out what to do... 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `height:100%;` on `.featured-image-container` sizes the height relative to the height of its container.

In this case, the height of the container is equal to the height of the content in the container (the natural height of the image).

If you manually set the height on `html,body` to `100%` then you'll find that the height of your div is now as you'd expect.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EyLHG/

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
.container{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;

}
img{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

**Update**

Also, setting the width of the image to `auto` will cause the width to be the default width of the image rather than of the container. Setting the `width` to be `100%` will fix this scaling issue:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EyLHG/2/

Comment: I think it is... is it not?

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: It's still not working.

http://zoesghanakitchen.co.uk/?p=445

That's the page. I have the page height @ 100%, the container @ 100% and the img @ 100%. Can't for the life of me work out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What do you want it to do? If you change `width:auto;` to `width:100%;` then it fills the entire space. Is that what you're after?

Comment: The point i was making in my update is that you can't set the height to be 100% because the image is constrained by its width. If you set both the height and the width, it fills the entire space.

Comment: Not quite. I want the image to be 100% of the browser height, and the correct width in proportion to it's (new) height. If you open the link in Chrome it display's it correctly...

Comment: you know what Jamie. I'm a massive tard. I set up the thumbnail selection wrong on wordpress.

If i put in the correct proportion thumbnail in the php (i.e.

 
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>

(not large) then Firefox does exactly what we wanted int he right way. WELL DONE. I think we'd solved it before I even asked the question because all your answers were BANG ON, it's just i'd made a mistake in the php.

**ANYONE READING THIS, JAMIE'S ANSWERS ARE CORRECT. Just check your output first...**

Comment: For that to be the case you'll need to see `height:100%` on `.entry-page-image`

Comment: Glad it's working for you @SamSlater. p.s. The Ghana Kitchen sounds nice, I might pop by some time :)

Comment: It's bloody lovely. I'm being paid in meals. If you're in London (or can be), I owe you a free meal. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

just saw your website, I think there is image still in below the browser as well, I think you might need to add ***position:relative;*** to .entry-page-image